# Difference in the end of lifetime rules?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime in **Notes** section has this code, reproduced here:

```
struct A {
  int* p;
  ~A() { std::cout << *p; } // if n outlives a, prints 123
};
void f() {
  A a;
  int n = 123; // if n does not outlive a, this is optimized out (dead store)
  a.p = &n;
}
```

What is it trying to say in this **Notes** section?

From what I understand, the code is UB (or is it) as it's clear that `n` does not outlive `a`.

What does it mean by:

> difference in the end of lifetime rules between non-class objects (end
>   of storage duration) and class objects (reverse order of construction)
>   matters

But it does not say matter **how**.

I am very confused by this entire section.

Comment: I'm not sure what they are trying to say in the notes section.  AFAIK this is UB per the standard.

Comment: @NathanOliver I think it might be insinuating that `n` does outlive `a` because `a` is destroyed just before the closing brace and `n` is destroyed at the closing brace. I'm not convinced that this is true, though.

Comment: I thought reverse order destruction would mean that `n` is destroyed before `a` leading to `UB`.

Comment: This is [core issue 2256](https://wg21.link/CWG2256). We took this example (which Clang "miscompiles" according to the current rules) from one of the core reflector posts on this subject.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is an odd aspect of C++'s lifetime rules. [[basic.life]/1 tells us](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.life#1) that an object's lifetime ends:

> - if `T` **is a class type with a non-trivial destructor** ([class.dtor]), the destructor call starts, or
> - the storage which the object occupies is released, or is reused by an object that is not nested within o ([intro.object]).

Emphasis added. `int` is not a "class type with a non-trivial destructor", so its lifetime *only ends* when the storage it occupies is released. By contrast, `A` is a class type with a non-trivial destructor", so its lifetime ends when the destructor gets called.

The storage for a scope is released when the scope exits, pursuant to [[basic.stc.auto]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.stc.auto):

> The storage for [variables with automatic storage duration] lasts until the block in which they are created exits.

But automatic variables are destroyed in accord with [[stmt.jump]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/stmt.jump#2):

> On exit from a scope (however accomplished), objects with automatic storage duration that have been constructed in that scope are destroyed in the reverse order of their construction.

Notice that the order of destruction is specified, but the order of automatic storage release is *not* specified. This means that the implementation could release the storage right after each variable is destroyed, or release it all at once later, or in some arbitrary other order.

Now, the fact that it uses the singular for storage ("the storage for ... lasts") rather than talking about each variable individually may suggest that the intent is for the storage as a whole to be released at once for that scope. But there is no explicit statement of this in the standard. So as long as a variable is destroyed before its storage is released, any ordering of destruction vs. release appears to be legal.

This means it is entirely possible for the code to work, for `n` to outlive `a`. But it is unspecified whether it *does* work.

Comment: So, the the destructor for `A` will be called before the function `f` exits, but I can't relate it with the quote you added from the standard. A little help would be appreciated.

Comment: in other words, the destructor is called from the scope of this function, before it exists. The latter can use the `p` member to access storage for the `n`, which is still legal.

Comment: But won't the memory for `n` be released before the destructor/memory release of `a`? Yes I know `n`'s memory is sitting there on the stack but surely the compiler is free to reuse it before starting the destruction/unallocating of `a`?

Comment: Thinking about it when `a`'s destructor is called the compiler will give the destructor function a stack frame. Isn't that likely to overwrite all the automatic variables destroyed before `a` in the scope?

Comment: @Galik, no, this is the whole point. In laymen terms, `a` liftetime ends before `{`, and n lifetime ends after `{`.

Comment: @SergeyA As far as I am aware, destroying an object involves calling its destructor (if applicable) and then freeing its memory. Surely **both** happen before moving on to the next object?

Comment: @SergeyA: Upon further investigation, things aren't quite that simple. My answer has been revised accordingly.

Comment: Just when I thought I mostly understood C++'s lifetime rules :/

Comment: @NicolBolas It still seems to me that it is an *assumption* that the compiler will call all the destructors before freeing all the memory. I think both the calling of destructors **and** the releasing of storage happen at the exit of the scope - in reverse order of allocation/construction. I still (from that wording) don't see why each object won't be destructed then deallocated in turn.

Comment: @Galik: "*I still (from that wording) don't see why each object won't be destructed then deallocated in turn.*" I'm not saying that it couldn't; I'm saying that it is not *required*. Which is why the cppreference page speaks in hypothetical terms about whether it works or not. Because it is unspecified.

Comment: Can we change the standard so that `int` variables live and die by the same rules as objects of class type?

Comment: @Brian: Who is "we"? Can the committee? Sure; there have been some discussion on that. Can random users on SO? No.

Comment: By "we" I meant the C++ community, by proposing to the committee that such a change be made. By "can", I meant whether or not this would have a decent chance at getting accepted.

Comment: I would not expect a request that storage and lifetime be tied to be accepted. As things exist now the compiler is able to calculate the total memory required for automatic storage and write function entry and exit code that allocates that memory as a single block. If object lifetime and storage were synchronized that allocation fiddling would have to be done every time an object were created or destroyed, and for no real gain.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir: That's not really what Brian is asking for. He's asking that calling an `int`'s destructor will end its lifetime. Right now, even if you called `n.~int();`, that would not actually end `n`'s lifetime.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir That's covered by as-if.

Comment: @Brian: What advantage is there to regarding PODS as having lifetime separate from the storage they occupy, versus allowing a compiler to treat loads and stores of seemingly-unrelated lvalues as generally unsequenced while specifying cases where compilers must recognize lvalues as related or perform certain operations in strict sequence?  What good reason is there for a compiler to *care* about the lifetime of an `int`?

Answer (score 10):

This example is borrowed from [Core Language Issue 2256](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#2256):

> **Section:** 6.8  [basic.life]     **Status:** drafting     **Submitter:** Richard Smith     **Date:** 2016-03-30
>
> According to 6.4 [basic.lookup] bullet 1.4, the following example has defined behavior because the lifetime of `n` extends until its storage is released, which is after `a`'s destructor runs:
>
> ```
>   void f() { 
>     struct A { int *p; ~A() { *p = 0; } } a; 
>     int n; 
>     a.p = &n; 
>   }
> ```
>
> It would be more consistent if the end of the lifetime of all objects, regardless of whether they have a non-trivial destructor, were treated the same.
>
> **Notes from the March, 2018 meeting:**
>
> CWG agreed with the suggested direction.

The key idea is, whether the lifetime of an object ends at its destruction or at the time its memory is released may affect the semantic of a program. In the example,

1. if the lifetime of `n` ends at the destruction of `n`, the program is undefined;
2. if the lifetime of `n` ends until the memory is released, the program has defined behavior<sup>1</sup>.

Hence it requires further discussion to determine when the lifetime of an object ends.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is because [Core Language Issue 2115](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#2115):

> **Section:** 9.6  [stmt.jump]     **Status:** drafting     **Submitter:** Richard Smith     **Date:** 2015-04-16
>
> The relative ordering between destruction of automatic variables on exit from a block and the release of the variables' storage is not specified by the Standard: are all the destructors executed first and then the storage released, or are they interleaved?
>
> **Notes from the February, 2016 meeting:**
>
> CWG agreed that the storage should persist until all destructions are complete, although the “as-if” rule would allow for unobservable optimizations of this ordering.

The intent is that the memory release of automatic variables happens after all destructions are complete.

Comment: Is there any real need for plain-old-data objects *have* a lifetime separate from that of the storage they occupy?  If the goal is to allow aliasing-related optimization, it would seem both simpler and more effective to simply say that loads and stores of seemingly-unrelated lvalues are generally unsequenced, and specify situations where lvaues must be recognized as related, or operations upon them recognized as sequenced.

Comment: @supercat: "*Is there any real need for plain-old-data objects have a lifetime separate from that of the storage they occupy?*" Yes. Scalar lifetime analysis can catch people using uninitialized memory and other similar errors. But that requires that scalars *have* lifetimes, that you can point to a piece of memory and know exactly the (nested set of) objects that live there.

Comment: Just to be clear: this means that CWG has agreed that this code snippet *should* have undefined behaviour, and the standard should be updated to make it so?

Comment: @NicolBolas: Having explicit directives to either say that a certain region of storage should be treated as holding Indeterminate Value, or that any bytes within a region of storage that hold Indeterminate Value should be changed to hold Unspecified values, would seem more useful, for purposes of diagnostics and optimization, than trying to use lifetime rules for that purpose.

Comment: @supercat: But there are "explicit directives" to do just that. They're called "destroying the object" and "creating an object without initializing it". They already exist and already have useful semantic meanings.

Comment: @NicolBolas: There is no facility to say "I want to create an object initialized with the contents of the underlying storage, but with Indeterminate Value changed to Unspecified Value", nor am I aware of any means of destroying an object without doing anything to the storage.  Further, the notion that objects' lifetime can be ended by overwriting the storage ends up with an annoying number of corner cases that needlessly and uselessly complicate or block optimizations.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Given `void test(int *p, double *q, int mode) { *p = 1; *q = 1.0; if (mode) *p = 1;}`, what can be said about the effect of each assignment on the lifetimes of any affected objects?

Comment: @Brian I'm not sure since I'm not a member of CWG.

Comment: @Brian Yes, that's the direction.